# Stuck in C++ data structure program

Tags: c++, data-structures

Write a program that prompts the user for a string and uses a recursive function to print the string backward. Do not use any global variables; use the appropriate parameters. Could you give me some hints, like pseudocode?

```
int stringbackwards(string a){                  
if()


else


}


int main(){

    string name;

    cout<<"Write a name: ";           
    cin>>name;

    cout<<"Backwards "<<stringbackwards(name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: People will help with something you have tried but please don't expect us to give you code.

Comment: Nobody is going to do your homework.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you use a recursion for that?
There is a good concept in c++ called iterators that already has this functionality implementet :)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rbegin/

So in your case:

```
cout<<"Backwards ";
for (std::string::reverse_iterator rit=name.rbegin(); rit!=name.rend(); ++rit)
{
    cout << *rit;
}
```

But to make it recursive, i would do it like this (Pseudocode).

```
function backwards(std::string& name, unsigned int length)
{
    unsigned int length = name.length();
    unsigned int currLength = length - 1;

    if (length > 0)
    {
         backwards(name, currLength);
    }

    std::cout << name[length - currLength - 1];
}
```

Comment: Quite right too, except this is presumably a homework question.

Comment: I have to use recursion because of my homework. ;) I dont think that function have to return an int.

Comment: So than do you homework ;)

Comment: See above - something like that but untested.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Say the string is "abcd". You would like to print "dcba". In other words, you are printing the last letter first.

Hence you will first go deep into recursion and then after coming back, print the letter 'a'.